# How do I embed a resource into an appx package?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to include data files, or images in a C# appx package. I've tried adding the files to the csproj, and enabled "Copy to Output Directory", but they don't wind up in the AppXLayouts dir.

I haven't found any hints on dev.windows.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio:

1. go to the Solution Explorer
2. find the images item
3. right click
4. select add
5. pick your pictures

This should cause them to be packaged.